# Proxy issue while cloning a repo in Docker image in Windows

Tags: git, docker, proxy, docker-for-windows, docker-proxy

I have a Docker image with the necessary proxy configuration. When I attempt to clone a Git repository in a container created from the image on a Linux server, the operation is successful. However, when I use the same image and create a container on Windows, the Git clone fails with below error in that. What configuration am I missing in my Windows Docker setup?

`fatal: unable to access 'url': The requested URL returned error: 403`

Comment: Error: 403 is HTTPS authentication error. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+The+requested+URL+returned+error%3A+403 You missed your credentials (token or password, credential cache, etc.)

Comment: In many ways it's often easier to clone the repository outside of Docker.  That lets you check in the Dockerfile; you don't need to worry about credentials or proxies in the image build; you can build an image off of a non-default branch or from uncommitted code; it avoids some layer-caching issues that might miss changes in the repository.